# jQuery not triggering event in hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to make a navigational menu that on click scrolls to a div positioned lower on the page. Initially it worked but as I added a CSS transition to highlight the text, the jQuery will no longer trigger the scrolling to happen upon clicking it.

```
$("#about, #about:hover").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#box1").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

The `#about` id is a part of the nav menu and will scroll to `#box1` on click. I've tried adding the hover state to the selector, changing it to `.trigger` rather than `.click` but I'm not seeing a simple solution. I've recreated the event in Chrome, Safari, and using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/be8afrw5/).

Is the JQuery conflicting with the transition, the hover state, or my code in general?

**EDIT:** It is working in the Fiddle example but the event still isn't happening when produced locally (everything is linked and correct with no errors in console).

Comment: Have you tried using [`$.hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of `:hover` css selector?

Comment: In your JSFiddle you forgot to add the jQuery resource. After adding it - it scrolled [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/be8afrw5/1/)

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar It is working in Fiddle but still isn't working locally. Using Google's 1.12.2 external link for the library here.

Comment: @Wikiti Haven't tried it, I'm more familiar with CSS transitions so that's what I used.

Comment: Check if you have any z-index in css which you recently added. May be z-index is stopping the event.

Comment: @VijendraKulhade No z-index used, the transition works fine but the JQuery isn't triggering the event to happen.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin since its working on JSFiddle and not locally, And looking at your code, its probably because your js is outside of `$(document).ready();`. Put it inside I believe it will solve it. Report back please :)

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar No change.

Comment: Is anything working related to jQuery? If you're pulling jQuery library in from an external link you need to be loading the local pages on a server (like XAMP or MAMP) if it's just an html page in the browser loaded through a file system it won't grab the external link to the jQuery plugin. If you're not running a local server then you need to include a local file

Comment: try `$(document).on('click', '#about', function(){});` instead of `.click(function(){});`. and also do you see any errors on console?

Comment: @RavishaHesh No result, not even on the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/be8afrw5/7/

Comment: You have to add jquery library, and there is a syntax error. You have to put `);` at the end after `}` (`});`)

Comment: @ShaunLoftin take the JS part from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/be8afrw5/11/) and put it in place of the JS part in your local copy. See if it works please

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Worked! Must have been my syntax, thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin you're welcome. Yes it was the `document.ready()` as I suspected. You probably had a typo when put it before. Anyway I just posted a full answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS code runs before the DOM is fully loaded.

Put the JS inside `document.ready();`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#about, #about:hover").click(function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#box1").offset().top
        },
            'slow');
    });

    $("#portfolio, #portfolio:hover").click(function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#box2").offset().top
        },
            'slow');
    });

    $("#social, #social:hover").click(function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#box3").offset().top
        },
            'slow');
    });

    $("#contact, #contact:hover").click(function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#box4").offset().top
        },
            'slow');
    });
});
```

See updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/be8afrw5/11/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work if your jQuery link and/or functions link are in the header.

It works for me if the js links are towards the end of your html like before the closing body tag.

Comment: Documentation suggests that the library is linked in the header. I've been linking it in the header but my problem was purely syntax.